# iOS Create custom photo album in Photos (addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName under iOS 5?)

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary

I wanted to know if its anyhow possible to create your own photo album in the iDevice's photo library ?

I know ALAsset's [addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:resultBlock:failureBlock:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetsLibrary/addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName%3aresultBlock%3afailureBlock%3a) , but it only works in iOS >= 5.0 . Is there a method that could support at least 4.3 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating customs albums is only created under ios 5. It's not possible under ios 4. Even the official apple photo app does not have a feature to create albums in the device itself under ios 4. Under ios 4 the only way to create albums is by iTunes photo syncing.

Cheers,

Hendrik