# Saving Video in an Album Created

Tags: iphone, ios, video, alassetslibrary

i have created an album using this code in AppDelegate methode

```
NSString *albumName=@"999Videos";
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:albumName
                         resultBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group) {
                             NSLog(@"added album:%@", albumName);
                         }
                        failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                            NSLog(@"error adding album");
                        }];
```

Now i want to save the recorded videos to this 999Videos album created.Not to the photosAlbum which i have done like this.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL])
    {
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL
                                    completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
```

The videos are saving but not in the 999Videos album.Could someone please tell me how can i save the videos to my custom album?

Comment: i need help with this please.

Comment: Please refer this link , May be it will helpful to you.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610708/ios-create-custom-photo-album-in-photos-addassetsgroupalbumwithname-under-ios-5

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After tearing my hair out over this finally i found the solution.Here is my code.

```
NSString *albumName=@"999 Videos";
                ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
                [library addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:albumName
                                         resultBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group) {
                                             NSLog(@"added album:%@", albumName);
                                            }
                                        failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                            NSLog(@"error adding album");

                                        }];

__block ALAssetsGroup* groupToAddTo;
    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum
                                    usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
                                            if ([[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName] isEqualToString:albumName]) {
                                                    NSLog(@"found album %@", albumName);
                                                    groupToAddTo = group;
                                                }
                                            }
                                          failureBlock:^(NSError* error) {
                                              NSLog(@"failed to enumerate albums:\nError: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                          }];


                [library assetForURL:assetURL
                              resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                                  // assign the photo to the album
                                  [groupToAddTo addAsset:asset];
                                  NSLog(@"Added %@ to %@", [[asset defaultRepresentation] filename], albumName);
                              }
                             failureBlock:^(NSError* error) {
                                 NSLog(@"failed to retrieve image asset:\nError: %@ ", [error localizedDescription]);
                             }];
```

Comment: how can we create assetURL ?