# How to save video to custom album?

Tags: ios, ios7, alassetslibrary

I'm trying to save a video made in an app to a custom album. 
I've tried the solution proposed on [Saving Video in an Album Created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569505/saving-video-in-an-album-created), however, these blocks are executed asynchronously resulting in my asset in the result block being nil.

I've succeeded in creating the album, writing a video to it doesn't seem to work with the above methods. I have no clue what's going on. Can someone give me a heads up on this?

Comment: did you try `- (void)assetForURL:(NSURL *)assetURL resultBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock)resultBlock failureBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)failureBlock` method? In the resultBlock you should have an non-nil asset object

Comment: Yes I actually do, assets keeps returning as nil. 
`[library assetForURL:assetURL
    resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
     //Add video to group
     [targetGroup addAsset:asset];
    }
   failureBlock:^(NSError* error) {
    //Error
   }];`

Comment: So where does the assetURL come from?

Comment: It's provided by the `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate` method `captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error`
Looks like this: `NSURL * @"file:///private/var/mobile/Applications/1BB71D35-A37E-4FE3-8D8D-F00DFA925086/tmp/output.mov"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url you got is a file url but not an ALAsset url.

You'll need to save that mov to camera roll first and add its asset reference  to the custom album.

Check out the example code in this tutorial.

http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/

Comment: The ALAsset url thing did the trick :) Thank you!
I have put the solution in a separate class on [GitHub: VideoAlbumManager](https://github.com/ikbenmartijn/VideoAlbumManager)

Comment: Nice to hear that and appreciate for the work! It will be useful for me in a short period. :D

Answer (score 0):

for video saving support, just add the function below to the category offered here:
http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/

```
 -(void)saveVideoLocalUrl:(NSURL*)assetURL toAlbum:(NSString*)albumName withCompletionBlock:(SaveImageCompletion)completionBlock
 {
    //add the asset to the custom photo album
    [self writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:assetURL completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)    {
       NSLog(@"error: %@", [error description]);

       [self addAssetURL: assetURL
              toAlbum:albumName
       withCompletionBlock:completionBlock];
    }];
 }
```