# Save Video into Custom Album iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios6, alassetslibrary, alasset

How to save video with my custom album .
I found one link but it don't work [Custom file manager](https://codeload.github.com/ikbenmartijn/VideoAlbumManager/zip/master)

It gives the url value is null.

```
[VideoAlbumManager addVideoWithAssetURL:outputFileUrl toAlbumWithName:@"Video Maker"];//outputfileurl is my video url from document directory
```

Give any suggestion for this..

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569505/saving-video-in-an-album-created and also check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610708/ios-create-custom-photo-album-in-photos-addassetsgroupalbumwithname-under-ios-5

Comment: I check those two links more than 10 times but i don't found anything. I send mail to your mail id.

Comment: check it and let you know.

Comment: from where you saving the videos?

Comment: Create The Album in library and then save in this album.

Comment: Flagged to moderator as I believe http://stackoverflow.com/users/3955793/divyesh-dobariya and http://stackoverflow.com/users/3801830/divyesh-dobariya are the same person. Also over a 2 minute period you have had 11 upvotes, investigation required.

Comment: You'll need to save that mov to camera roll first and add its asset reference to the custom album.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this link to save the video..
[GitHub Link](https://github.com/Kjuly/ALAssetsLibrary-CustomPhotoAlbum)

Import this two files into your project.

1. ALAssetsLibrary+CustomPhotoAlbum.h
2. ALAssetsLibrary+CustomPhotoAlbum.m

Then in your save IBAction method write this lines..

```
if(UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(outputFilePath)){

    NSURL *muyrl=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFilePath];
    [library saveVideo:muyrl toAlbum:albumName withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error)
    {
        if (error!=nil) {
            NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
        } 
    }];
```

Where.. **outputfilepath** is your videopath and if you have url then save it with URL name.
**library** is ALAssetLibrary that define in .h file
**albumName** is your Album name what do you want..I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)SaveToalbum{
NSString *finalFileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/video.mov"];
NSString *videoOutputPath = [NSHomeDirectory()
                             stringByAppendingPathComponent:finalFileName];

NSString* webStringURL = [videoOutputPath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL* url =[NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];

ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];
if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:url])
{
    NSURL *clipURl = url;
    [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:clipURl completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
     {

     }];

}

}
```

You can try with it. It will be helpful for you. Just go through  "http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/" link and download the sample project.

> 1. Drag-drop two file `"ALAssetsLibrary+CustomPhotoAlbum.h"` and  `"ALAssetsLibrary+CustomPhotoAlbum.m"` into your project and add `"AssetsLibrary.framework"`.  Now you are ready for coding.Just go on your `ViewController.h` Class and import the `<AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>` and `"ALAssetsLibrary+CustomPhotoAlbum.h"` file.
> 2. Create a object for `ALAssetsLibrary` and write a block for saving the video file in custom album,just like this,

```
[ALAssetsLibraryObject addAssetURL:clipURl toAlbum:AlbumName withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error)
{   
    if (error!=nil) {
        NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description])
    } 
}];
```